# Why is it only taking number as input?

Tags: java

This code is only showing output as

> Enter Name of the item you want to add Enter the price of item

While it should take the name before it takes the double as input.

```
newMenu = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please select on of the menuItems \n 1. Premium \n 2. Discount \n 3. Standard ");
FileWriter file = new FileWriter(f,true);

//Create an instance of the PrintWriter class using output as the argument
PrintWriter abc = new PrintWriter(file);

if(newMenu.nextInt()==1){
    abc.println("Premium");
    System.out.println("Enter Name of the item you want to add");
    String name=newMenu.nextLine();
    abc.println(m1.getNoOfItems()+1+" "+name);

    System.out.println("Enter the price of item");
    double price=newMenu.nextDouble();
    abc.println(price);
    m1.setNoOfItems(m1.getNoOfItems()+1);               
}
```

Comment: Just check the bracket closure, after the if condition

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
if(newMenu.nextInt() == 1){
```

You can use `newMenu.nextLine()` instead like this :

```
if (Integer.parseInt(newMenu.nextLine()) == 1) {
```

---

> While it should take the name before it take the double as input.

You don't get this scenario because you don't consume the all the line.

Comment: @AmritDumre because `nextInt() reads an integer but does not read the escape sequence "\n"` yo can read more about that here [scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to consume the `\n` after `.nextInt()` Do

```
if(newMenu.nextInt()==1){
    newMenu.nextLine();
    //..rest of code
```